# Acceptable use of Thread.Sleep()

Tags: c#, sleep

I'm working on a console application which will be scheduled and run at set intervals, say every 30 minutes. Its only purpose is to query a Web Service to update a batch of database rows.

The Web Service API reccommends calling once every 30 seconds, and timeout after a set interval. The following pseudocode is given as an example:

```
listId := updateList(<list of terms>)
LOOP
  WHILE NOT isUpdatingComplete(listId)
END LOOP
statuses := getStatuses(“LIST_ID = {listId}”)
```

I have coded this roughly in C# as:

```
int callCount = 0;
while( callCount < 5 && !client.isUpdateComplete(listId, out messages) )
{
    listId = client.updateList(options, terms, out messages);
    callCount++;
    Thread.Sleep(30000);
}
// Get resulting status...
```

Is it OK in this situation to use Thread.Sleep()? I'm aware it is not generally good practice but from reading reasons not to use it this seems like acceptable usage.

Thanks.

Comment: Your use of `Thread.Sleep` is perfectly acceptable

Comment: The console application will be scheduled? Why not just schedule it for every 30 minutes if that's the case? The better solution would be a windows service that uses a timer to call the method.

Comment: Why not? What are the reasons not to use it?

Comment: @Ray: It looks like this particular code only takes 2.5 minutes to run (5 loops with a 30 second wait between iterations).  It sounds like those loops are *scheduled* to be executed once every 30 minutes.  In other words, the loop doesn't sit for 30 minutes..

Comment: @Ray I think there is confusion between the console application being scheduled to run every 30 minutes vs the web service's API recommending that the caller make retry attempts at 30 second intervals.  In this case, it looks like Thread.Sleep is being used to space out the retries, not as a mechanism for scheduling the console application's work.  The fact that the console application runs every 30 minutes is an unrelated concern.

Comment: @Dr.Wily'sApprentice and ChrisLively, you're right. I missed the difference between the 30 seconds and 30 minutes.

Comment: @Chris Lively/@Dr. Wily's Apprentice - Exactly - Thanks for clarifying.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Thread.Sleep` ensures the current thread doesn't return until *at least* the specified milliseconds have passed.   There are plenty of places it's appropriate to do that, and your example seems fine, assuming it's running on a background thread.

Some example places you don't want to use it - on the UI thread or where you need to do exact timing.

Comment: I think that your qualification "assuming it's running on a background thread" is ok, but in this case the application appears to be a console application that will be run automatically as a scheduled task, so I think in this case it's not necessary to ensure that it runs on a background thread.  If this were an interactive application, then I would totally agree with your qualification.

Comment: I mean background thread by any thread running in the background, i.e. not a UI thread.  Service threads I would consider background threads.  (I'm not referring to `IsBackground` on thread objects, which simply refers to how threads are destroyed/cleaned up on app exit, IIRC).  Oops, didn't see you said Console.  Yup that's debatable terminology, but it's not really a background thread, quite right.  I might then argue that a Console app isn't so appropriate..

Comment: Ah, I get what you mean. :) I wasn't intending to argue semantics, but your comment has made me realize that in this case, the "main thread" of the console application could sort of be considered as a "background" thread because there is no user interaction.

Answer (score 5):

Generally speaking, `Thread.Sleep` is like any other tool: perfectly OK to use, except when it's terribly misused. I disagree with the "not generally good practice" part, which is the result of people abusing `Thread.Sleep` when they should be doing something else (i.e. blocking on a synchronization object).

In your case the program is single-threaded, it has no UI (i.e. the thread has no message loop) and you do not want to synchronize with external events. Therefore `Thread.Sleep` is just fine.

Answer (score 3):

The general objection against Sleep() is that it wastes a Thread.

In your case there is only 1 Thread (maybe 2) so that is not really a problem.

So I think it looks fine (but I would sleep 29 seconds to cut some slack).

Comment: I'm not convinced about the 29 sec thing.. Amazon require 60 sec between some API calls.  `Thread.Sleep(60 * 1000)` still gives an error talking about 60 sec delay in rare cases and so, in *that* specific case I sleep for 62 sec, i.e. give it *more* slack.  YMMV and all that..

Answer (score 1):

It's fine, except that you cannot interrupt it once it goes into sleep, without aborting the thread (which is not recommended).

That's why a `ManualResetEvent` might be a better idea, since it can be signalled ("awaken") from a different thread.

Answer (score 1):

you could stick with the Thread.Sleep method. But it would be more elegant to schedule it to run every 30 minutes - so you don't have to take care of the waiting inside your application.

Answer (score 0):

Thread.Sleep isn't the best for executing periodic logic. Thread.Sleep(n) means your thread will relinquish control for n milliseconds. There is no guarantee that it will regain control after n milliseconds, it depends on the CPU load.

Answer (score 0):

If you are locking the thread for 30 mins case you should schedule a windows task every 30 mins, so the program executes and then ends. That way you are not locking a thread for so long.

For shorter times, like 30 secs / 1 min, System.Thread.Sleep() is perfectly fine. For more than 5 mins i would use a windows task. (Im spanish i think on the english version are called like that, im talking about the tasks you schedule from the control panel ;-) )